# How to make a prepopulated form in ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I have a list of clients in a database with various information about them. I need to print all of them out with a slidedown form with their current information already there, and the ability to add or change it.

I am able to print out all the clients and their info but when I try to edit the form it is disabled even though there is no disabled attribute set.

Here is the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var context = new U2XPlanningAutomationToolEntities();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Clients";
        IEnumerable<Client> data = context.Database.SqlQuery<Client>(query);
        List<Client> clients = new List<Client>(data);

        ViewBag.Clients = clients;
        string email = Session["email"] as string;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            return View();
        }

        return View("../Account/Login");
    }
```

The View

```
@foreach (var client in ViewBag.Clients)
{
    string plan_changes = client.plan_changes;
    string critical_milestones = client.critical_milestones;
    string pdd = client.pdd;
    string inbound = client.inbound;
    string outbound = client.outbound;
    string other = client.other;

    <div class="row client">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><span id="@client.id" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus dropdownBtn"></span><p>@client.name</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><p>@client.oep_start</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><p>@client.oep_end</p></div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 text-right"><button id="@client.id" class="btn btn-primary delete-client">Delete</button></div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 slider" id="slider_@client.id">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateClient", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@client.id" />
                    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.plan_changes, "Plan Changes")
                    @*<textarea name="plan_changes" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="2">@plan_changes</textarea>*@
                    @Html.TextArea("plan_changes", plan_changes, new { @class = "form-control" })
                   
                    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.critical_milestones, "Critical Milestones")
                    @Html.TextArea("critical_milestones", critical_milestones, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.pdd, "Plan Document Design")
                    @Html.TextArea("pdd", pdd, new { @class = "form-control" })

                    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.inbound, "Inbound")
                    @Html.TextArea("inbound", inbound, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.outbound, "Outbound")
                    @Html.TextArea("outbound", outbound, new { @class = "form-control" })

                    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.other, "Other")
                    @Html.TextArea("other", other, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            }
            
        </div>
    </div>

    }
```

If my approach seems weird to you it might be because I am brand new to MVC ASP.NET, I am coming from a PHP background.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try with @Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.other)... etc..

Comment: Do you mean you cannot edit the data in textarea?I test your code,and textarea data can be edited.

Comment: Hm I could not edit the textarea on my end, I will test on another computer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a `IEnumerable<Client>` in you view instead of putting it into a viewbag. Can you try to pass the id in the `Html.BeginForm`. Do you have an `UpdateClient` method in your `HomeController` class?